# Can itextsharp.xmlworker render embedded images?

Tags: c#, html, image, itext

I would like to create dynamic PDF documents using HTML and dynamic images. My code works fine with standard HTML and full paths for the images, but when I try to embed the image inline in the document I get the error

> Exception Details: System.IO.IOException: The document has no pages.

Is there a way to embed the images without an HTTP call per image? I don't want that because I think it will cause scalability issues and the images are sensitive.

Here is my code that gives the IOException:

```
    public ActionResult MakePdf()
    {
        string html = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
             <!DOCTYPE html 
                 PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""
                ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"">
             <html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">
                <head>
                    <title>Minimal XHTML 1.0 Document with W3C DTD</title>
                </head>
              <body><img src='data:image/png;base64,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' width='62' height='80' style='float: left; margin-right: 28px;' /></body></html>";

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html);

        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50))
            {
                using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output))
                {
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    document.Open();

                    XMLWorkerHelper xmlWorker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                    xmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, null);
                    document.Close();
                    output.Position = 0;

                    return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We need to write our own ImageTagProcessor to support processing of base 64 images:

```
public class CustomImageTagProcessor : iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Image
{
    public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> attributes = tag.Attributes;
        string src;
        if (!attributes.TryGetValue(HTML.Attribute.SRC, out src))
            return new List<IElement>(1);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(src))
            return new List<IElement>(1);

        if (src.StartsWith("data:image/", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
            var base64Data = src.Substring(src.IndexOf(",") + 1);
            var imagedata = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagedata);

            var list = new List<IElement>();
            var htmlPipelineContext = GetHtmlPipelineContext(ctx);
            list.Add(GetCssAppliers().Apply(new Chunk((iTextSharp.text.Image)GetCssAppliers().Apply(image, tag, htmlPipelineContext), 0, 0, true), tag, htmlPipelineContext));
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can inject this new processor into the HtmlPipelineContext:

```
        using (var doc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
        {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            var html = @"<img src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAD4AAABQCAMAAAB24TZcAAAABGdBTUEAANbY1E9YMgAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAQWRvYmUgSW1hZ2VSZWFkeXHJZTwAAAGAUExURdSmeJp2SHlbQIRoSUg2J499a8KebqeHZuGufBEVJPz7+3NWPVxGMduwhPXEktnX1mtROLq7t5WDc2VMNv3LmKB8TMSidMbFxLGlmXlhSMSddpJUL+y8i3VlVqedlOzr6gUIF2lXRLCLY4ZyXLyYaYhtUYiJhJFyU1dBLLiVZnlwZrWRY/Hx8b+2rbySaJh9YqeooDw4NygnKvvJlpyblzksIUhGRryYckc7MPjGlKODX5x8VVA8K+azgM3FvDInHK2JW2ZbUOHh4Xt2cFpaWKeAUM6kel1RRJmUjo5vSrWzrJJ1WFhLQCQmMuK1iJiMgmthWPPCkOm3hEtBOunm5LCNXnJtZquEXmNkYvG+i7Ctq+y5hrWRbKqSeaN/WqmFVYFgQh8aGOa4isWkd8mcby4vONDNy0AwI5h2U19JMxkdLzIuL1JBMjQ3P5Z6Ve6/j93c2+Xi34KAfJ5/Xvj4+O/u7sSKVJd4Wo6QjXE+IeOwfQcNJoBeQ8Gdbf/Mmf///5GX6NEAAAcrSURBVHja3JbpX9pIGMchiWkgEaOBtaGinBLEyopFBeMqtYKI4kGt2lILFsUoXa3WdZcc/dd3JheHAvaz7/Z5Ec2Q7/yeaw7Lz/9klv8rfnM+Orz5cXLjZsL+67h9eCq9Vaxvzc6v3W6+/TX85kN6ixdokkQQCaE5vrg28Qv4a2yFQcpSi/HzH6efi+/UaEAwWAtepuvv3tw/B//hqZGQqDFSmyHC7v0z8EldlZQQEgTfMgF23h8/T+gEhQGrcQYrMBKVtvfDb4qU/j3DMK3SdIKWsNs++M1iS8R8W/gULyG1771w+/stQWpTpFpzByb09MRHEwaoxUxToGtaZiBrE72cXzMyhcDiIRgCHxJPIxKt5aF23gMf0iquz8BJmAAFpUStxvG0xIA3arcHPsvrJM1wvFTDeEGQeKCewCo1jgRDwKuJrrh9C3osIfyiz+NboZFKxU0xJEYmeJbBhPoKiKyMDXfHd0mJWSETnoKiKCmgSioFDKFr4T1lbn/fgkHf+PGu+A+A12imMqdAqzNUXlFCFP+gOD41CKJBcCB4bKSnOmitB5VWSgnMrSjhCnu8D1hoS1xP/KcH1BhZdGi4c4VNAh/I5PGyRjdQqje+A6YXPIpup/DhHlMUh44f1hAJ6x77z3OwVjG/0ml7Ot4gOWnxvkfbALw+2EnPGc43ojWk3qNt7hdpiSp0ajcMukHQPB/4o3vPf8TKQgc+pqXdkpEtgGewE7THel/j66dtdBLA1XAYRXK8AGbxC/6RHvjbCuOE0Kklk8lcg/+OicaJcOhfTflTVYCHuYvX3XH7QCxcUAol9i6VursLha+VfcLPHwamZjfSAgxi6QId6oFnC5awsjdoWYjFPrOlB3QONAtJjrwsetiq2jkzgfc9nPdklJBDyXvGj+Zf+jIKe7pPoNFoOHwyoyaQKFcD9z3wzbwSGnT6fCMB9u5UmWMLYwTJQo5QC2AB6r122ukBJeVWnA6HIwlLnp/bI/w5wI3tJR3LjcZMbvVzL/xHwOG+M6s2mFeSjRm0QRyDYnyCOEv/0fOYGM/vha4N3J1S5hoZhCAcYBro/AwV63NIjafuzL4rLSjOZYKeIT45j9XUnQTs/Y7Inbqp/pABeIPBqsTystr0/pd9T9jprZIGO9CHa4gTPHairxr/eP/rwai+YdzlWQfALSHu4qTxfHxiQKVTaBINvfCjDFo1Fmzjor/zP+0BNXdgxSTdqRe5w0bT2hq+293mdWDOSJ5DWbgwd4uGpSPxXW5WGzGddhYWHsDRguqpO5x9jjq4HY3BnjtcRRGGe/Xqn38YC6SraVt84jnXwo0FgC8kOK7s+mv91St6RhVnZ72Vqeln4EM+cFY43SHgdj584c9ormdFbx3Jbk73v9PuvNCCvx67ntPzlmG2xUvUhQpZz9roxHdwXx4e7Yb/fdXc7o81PFcUxW2ry+Wy5miM4gQkEAh0uxKfXWbdLXs1XGxZURRnXZpZrVbXegT/rUvm571itnncQPctWZso2hAdd61GIzIuf32y5zduL0VxtwQPWG2vB7QP0OKKVaejOI7L8lP4+S3r+wY+zSZfGPvGPlFlt8FQ3BCPQPYpfOjWs3QHtMVLJqmU0NLe9XVhsBpOwyER0+D1oE534t8Hsn/KctwLokxUgeunD6FwCA2xMGtAPAdhjkr55afwoaksGpHlAKTnWUK9ZIAt15k/U+mK5voSuoI9Vre/fZPOBcFQKg4+PXsXg7urVra0Stvqmud4mTp4hN/s+lAIy8ErIC7Oz8aITzqegYkUL4tawQ+ivEvudP7Gt6SPpCpewJ8BfN+pb/aq71dG2kjayLuJ3/vC+gB+EBe9Xm/8KEQs67hShMmgIRsNylFuFe9UL1IGHXHNAtr77ZYN7htNB8LxJmCnyaBZULpJ6/g4ZZQCX83FAS1u3675xnTaX/GKFdLl+gIaDZeFpU78rS9oDnzZEmHstqPJKc9n90LJPThyBUZIVRtMv8Q1v9Xx8bzxigddWo1t7yZ//zgSCwRiK6CO0PUD2OR4hMnhHfiPtYiJr4a8Jj4MbHNe7UC4RtTfc5wsd+DD6RbxxTZ8chtkrcJGIlqX41GqTVzFp3wmfmCNi5rNT74Z3nwHi2BjZW11AtdzgvxIfSBl4l/Klzr+bfLvzSNYA1u9xTfmz8f4lLmA5HWfgV8eTa7BEohxox1xeZ1F5Ef4fTrYnL4oGjb7QZ3JVgk2W4KJPMZvmWbo9KWJ27QsXKHm3DkhJT/Gs6z55lo0abV5wCSL5txL/CMa4PYPUXN+5qwTj68aXwa5MP4Efj/VDA4TW3BV3PQMp7Wlgnfg555mcPFO8RbXMbXv8Oh6pG3J7IRM8bq3Q/zKLFqUQ3GteNYvbepG1XG57O0Qt9Hmd1bOKC1qbZH/zbK78FWzYMJ2aZoXPq7kr8ZvORr+iUSjJzQb/Gpa5l8BBgBZTppAyfsf0wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' width='62' height='80' style='float: left; margin-right: 28px;' />";

            var tagProcessors = (DefaultTagProcessorFactory)Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
            tagProcessors.RemoveProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG); // remove the default processor
            tagProcessors.AddProcessor(HTML.Tag.IMG, new CustomImageTagProcessor()); // use our new processor

            CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
            cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCSS()); 
            var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);
            cssResolver.AddCss(@"code { padding: 2px 4px; }", "utf-8", true);
            var charset = Encoding.UTF8;
            var hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(new CssAppliersImpl(new XMLWorkerFontProvider()));
            hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(tagProcessors); // inject the tagProcessors
            var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, writer));
            var pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);
            var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
            var xmlParser = new XMLParser(true, worker, charset);
            xmlParser.Parse(new StringReader(html));
        }
        Process.Start("test.pdf");
```

Comment: Nice job! I was trying to get a custom `IImageProvider` to work but never thought to try a custom `img` tag!

Comment: Awesome! I read about that this morning http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html but hadn't started implementation yet. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Gread example. But the code works great but in Acrobat Reader, the first page is not rendered correctely. Text is not shown. Is there any known issue with this?

Comment: How to use this in XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList? I need to add paragraphs in HTML to the PDF.... not to perform a whole HTML to PDF conversion.

Comment: it worked if i have one page string but my string is too long so it is showing error: document has no pages.   thank you.

Comment: `document has no pages` means you have forgotten to add any PDF objects to the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string originalFile = "Original1.pdf";
            string copyOfOriginal = "Re-copia.pdf";

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(archivo);

            System.IO.FileStream stream = new FileStream(originalFile, FileMode.CreateNew);
            System.IO.BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            writer.Close();

            PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(originalFile);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(copyOfOriginal, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper object to write
            // Data from iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to FileStream object
            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs))
            {

                int pageCount = reader1.NumberOfPages;

                // Create New Layer for Watermark
                PdfLayer layer = new PdfLayer("WatermarkLayer", stamper.Writer);
                // Loop through each Page
                for (int i = pageCount; i <= pageCount; i++)
                {
                    // Getting the Page Size
                    Rectangle rect = reader1.GetPageSize(i);



                    // Get the ContentByte object
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamper.GetUnderContent(i);

                    // Tell the cb that the next commands should be "bound" to this new layer
                    cb.BeginLayer(layer);
                    cb.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 50);

                    PdfGState gState = new PdfGState();
                    cb.SetGState(gState);


                    string codbartest = codBarras;
                    BarcodePDF417 bcpdf417 = new BarcodePDF417();
                    //Asigna el código de barras en base64 a la propiedad text del objeto..
                    bcpdf417.Text = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(codbartest);
                    Image imgpdf417 = bcpdf417.GetImage();
                    imgpdf417.SetAbsolutePosition(50, 50);
                    imgpdf417.ScalePercent(100);
                    cb.AddImage(imgpdf417);
                    // Close the layer
                    cb.EndLayer();
                }[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: your answer completely ignores that the op is asking about this in a html-to-pdf use case...

Comment: Fue implemetado en web services para ser consumido por html, este es sólo parte del código basado en un ejemplo.

Comment: Please use English here.