# Can <img> tag inside html format mail be converted to image in pdf?

Tags: image, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have `<img>` tag inside html format mail like below:

```
<img src="cid:image001.png@01CF3975.B5497200">
```

How to convert this tag to a image in pdf? (I'm using iTextSharp.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: iTextSharp by itself will not do it. You can write your own logic, see this answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/a/19398426/231316

Comment: Thanks, @Chrishaas. Let me take a look.