# image src not reading base64 string in razor view

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, base64

```
<div style="height:180px;">
        <table id="tblheader" style="border:none 0px black;width:100%;background:none;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    @{
                         foreach (var ImageDataInfo in Model.JobImages.ImageDataInfo)
                         {
                            <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;">
                                <img src="@ImageDataInfo.ImageData" 
                                style="width:100px;height:100px;align-content:center;" />
                            </td>
                         }
                     }
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

`ImageDataInfo.ImageData` is a base64 string. The image does not get loaded. Please help.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: It was an issue with the Itextsharp pdf rendering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389999/can-itextsharp-xmlworker-render-embedded-images

Comment: the above link helped in solving

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageDataInfo.ImageData)" style="width:100px;height:100px;align-content:center;" />
```